# How can I ignore properties on the source when the property is null using AutoMapper?

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, dto

I have a scenario where I pass an existing object  to be duplicated in a generically typed sort of way. I have an entity hierarchy tree with matching set of dto classes as follows:
Plan
--->Roles
-------->Features  // many to many relationship.

The features are a many to many relationship. When I duplicate I run through the plan and the role Ids and reset them to 0. At this point the many to many relationship is broken. Also,  the map doesn't work because the role ids are not recreated upon insert. In order for the save to work the features must be ignored. So my entity after the ignore looks like this.

Plan

--->Roles

Dto still looks like this:

PlanDto

--------RoleDto

----------------FeaturesDto

Next, I need to send the updated copy of the PlanDto and RoleDto so a naturally run:

```
return Mapper.Map(plan, plandto);
```

The feature collection is null on the source object and the destination has a collection of the original many to many items. It is okay that the many to many items don't have matching role ids because there is no FeatureDto.RoleId property. The plan and roles will have new ids and then I can run a call against the old features lists and the new role id 
    _planService.AddRoleFeatures(plandto);

```
public void AddRoleFeatures(PlanDto plandto)
{
   foreach(var role in plandto.Roles) 
   foreach(var feature in role.Features) { feature.RoleId = role.Id; }
}
```

My mapper now works because I mapped the FeatureDto items to the correct many to many table items and the role ids are now correct. 
I have looked everywhere in AutoMapper and nothing seems to allow me to preserve my collection on the destination type when the source type is null. Though, many things seemed promising all the results lead one of the three problems, error, null, an empty collection.

I looked at the AutoMapper.Collections package but it looks like it is geared towards merging lists and when the collection is not there it doesn't preserve the destination list as needed.

Comment: I am starting to think that automapper can't relate those original ids back to the old one is where the problem lies.

Comment: But AM.Collection can. So you should use that combined with conditions maybe.

Comment: It would be nice. The AM Collection seems to have more to do with cascading from the source not the destination. Therefore, if the sources is empty I think it would just clear out my required fields.

Comment: I'm sure you can handle that case yourself.

Comment: It seems as though the am collections is not up to speed with aspnetcore. However, i was able to create a generic framework to update entities in the way that I was hoping. Updates now look like this. _planService.Update(plan, s => s.With(plan, p => s.With(p.Roles, r => r.Features))); It clears items and updates items including foreign key relations.